# Swagger OpenApi sends empty value "" instead of null and this ends up giving a 400 Bad Request status

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm doing a rest api in spring boot and I need to receive 3 normal values and a file, as you can see in the image below.

[endpoint image in swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjxmB.png)

My problem is that it is not mandatory to send the file, so when I make the request without the file, instead of going null it goes "" which is considered a string and this ends up giving status 400, because it is waiting for a type MultipartFile.

My method in spring boot:

```
@Operation(tags = {"Contato"}, summary = "Atualizar contato", description = "Atualiza os dados de um contato ativo a partir do ID.")
@PutMapping(path = "/atualizarContato",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseDto atualizarContato(@ModelAttribute ContatoUpdateDto contatoDto) throws IOException {// fazer a logica}
```

My class, I even tried to put the default value in @Schema but it doesn't work.

```
package app.api.denuncia.Dto;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class ContatoUpdateDto {
    
    @Schema(description = "O identificador (ID) do contato", required = true)
    private int id;
    
    @Schema(description = "O nome do contato", required = true)
    private String nome;

    @Schema(description = "O número de telefone do contato")
    private String telefone;

    @Schema(description = "Imagem que representa o contato")
    private MultipartFile logotipo;

    public ContatoUpdateDto() {
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MultipartFile getLogotipo() {
        return logotipo;
    }

    public void setLogotipo(MultipartFile logotipo) {
        this.logotipo = logotipo;
    }
}
```

I just need that instead of sending "" it sends null.

The error:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXND3.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERX90.png)

Comment: dynamically, based on whether a frontend input field is "" or not, the MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE head needs to included or not in the HTTP GET/POST request. When the submit form button is clicked, check the input field for "" and accordingly use a separate API (backend code) that does not included MULTIPART_... key word (once you get it working you can optimize the code).

Comment: for now my goal is not to consume the api from an interface but to use it only for tests in swagger

Comment: I have a solution, but the normal values are in the parameter and the file is in the request body. Is this considered normal, having both parameters and the request body in a request?

Comment: header, 'Content-Type:' is processed by the web server, so the header has to be modify accordingly (based on the spec outlined in your question) before the request hits/gets to the web server. How to modify the request before getting to the backend web server? Modify swagger code or create a NodeJS webserver in front of the Tomcat server that's accepting the request, ... .